# Unable to create k8s 1.10 cluster on GKE (us-east1-d)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

`gcloud container clusters create --cluster-version 1.10 --zone us-east1-d ...` returns with the error message `ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=No valid versions with the prefix "1.10" found.`.

The GKE release notes https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/release-notes#february-11-2019, indicates the specific kubernetes version is still supported.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using looks correct, but support for k8s 1.10 is being phased out on GKE, as per the GKE release notes entry of February 11, 2019:

> ### Coming soon
>
> We expect the following changes in the coming weeks. This information is not a guarantee, but is provided to help you plan for upcoming changes.
>
> 25% of the upgrades from 1.10 to 1.11.6-gke.2 will be complete.
>      Version 1.11.6-gke.8 will be made available.
>      **Version 1.10 will be made unavailable.**

Have you tried with the full version, say `1.10.12-gke.7`?

`gcloud container clusters create --cluster-version 1.10.12-gke.7 --zone us-east1-d ...`

Alternatively, use 1.11, because it looks like GKE is moving that way anyhow.